# get multiple results at once

Tags: php, html

My code works by getting the ID before the .htm I wanted it to do with multiple links in a row instead of 1 by 1

if anyone wants to see how it works: https://cleberrafael.com.br/freepik/fp.php

```
<?PHP
  if (isset($_POST['execute']))
  {
    if ($_SESSION['token'] == $token) {
      $url = $_POST['url'];
      $stepOne = explode("_", $url);
      
     if(!empty($stepOne[1])){
      $stepTwo = explode(".htm", $stepOne[1]);
        if(!empty($stepTwo[0])){
            $id = $stepTwo[0];
            $status = "success";
            $msg = "https://www.freepik.com/download-file/".$id; 
        }
        else {
           $status = "warning";
           $msg = "Cannot Parse URL";
        }
      }
     else {
        $status = "warning";
        $msg = "Link Errado Amigo";
      }
          
      if ($status == "success") {
            echo '<div class="alert alert-'.$status.'">
                  <strong>Pronto LIND!</strong> '.$msg.'
                </div>';
      } else if($status == "warning") {
            echo '<div class="alert alert-'.$status.'">
                  <strong>Failed!</strong> '.$msg.'
                </div>';
      } else {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">
                  <strong>Error!</strong> UNKNOWN
                </div>';
      }
          
    } else {
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">
                  <strong>Invalid Token!</strong> ^_^.
                </div>';
    }
  }
```

?>

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do, and most of us aren't inclined to follow links to people's sites. Instead, try to make a very simple example for this site. Remove the session and post stuff, and just hard code a sample string in there. Then explain what you want to get out of the code, along with what you are currently getting.

Comment: Hello Chris, actually this site I made, is a platform where I put a link to a site and it gives me its file ID, example: site.com.br/vetor/1444363.htm then I click and it gives me the result of the ID before the htm: 1444363 I wanted to put several site.com.br/vetor one under the other or by comma, instead of doing 1 by 1 I would like to receive the result of 10 link example

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, this line `$url = $_POST['url'];` will ideally hold multiple separated by commas, right? Can you, just for discussion purposes on this site, manually set `$url` equal to exactly what you would put your form, such as `$url = 'example.com/123,example.com/345';`. And then, I'm assuming you want an array? So can you also post what you'd like this array to look like, such as `$ids = [123, 345];`. Session and POST stuff make it harder to discuss because it requires extra things that aren't related to the problem.